# Specifying wild card patterns when invoking make targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I define:

```
# makefile
.FORCE:

foo-bar: .FORCE
  @echo "$@"

foo-biz: .FORCE
  @echo "$@"

.PHONY: foo-bar foo-biz
```

And I write on the command line:

```
$: make foo-bar foo-biz
```

---

Then is there a way for me to, somehow, write:

```
$: make foo-*
```

for example?

Comment: You would have to add a phony no-op rule `foo: foo-bar foo-baz` to your makefile. In other words, not really.

Comment: You *could* write a makefile that would do what you want, namely deduce from the target `foo-*` that you want to build all targets that start with `foo-`, but it would be a pretty fearsome beast. So if you actually need it, or you're trying to challenge yourself, sure; if you're looking for a quick solution to save yourself some work, no.

Comment: @Beta if we restrict the solution to the one single `%` wildcard which is natively supported, the solution is not that fearsome, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works but it only supports the one single `%` wildcard of native `make` pattern matching. Moreover I didn't analyze its impact on pattern rules etc.

```
PATTERN_GOALS := $(foreach g,$(MAKECMDGOALS),$(if $(findstring %,$(g)),$(g)))
force-on-pattern = $$(if $$(filter $(PATTERN_GOALS),$$@),$$(eval FORCE+=$$@))

# make FORCE a simple expanded variable
FORCE := 


.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo: $(force-on-pattern)
    echo $@

fooa: $(force-on-pattern)
    echo $@

fooab: $(force-on-pattern)
    echo $@

foob: $(force-on-pattern)
    echo $@

$(PATTERN_GOALS): $$(FORCE) ;
```

Test:

```
$ make foo%
fooab
fooa
foob
foo

$ make fooa%
fooab
fooa

$ make fooab%
fooab

$ make fooab
echo fooab
fooab

$ make foo%b
fooab
foob
```

You can have a look at the [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) and specifically the `glob-match` function for a `make`-native glob matcher but this is, as @Beta noticed, the realm of 'fearsome beast' `make` programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Since globbing happens in the shell before the make program even starts, you could have files in the repository named like the rules you want globbable:

```
touch foo-bar foo-biz
make foo-*
# executes 'make foo-bar foo-biz'
```

This works with real files too (not just .FORCE or PHONY), but only if the files already exist.